# Amazon S3, why is logging turn off by default and does turning it on have any impact?

Tags: performance, logging, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've just turn logging on in S3 so I can... well, log.

I was wondering why it is turned off by default and if turning it on has any impact on cost or on the performance of S3 transfers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's turned off because you don't need it by default. 
I don't care what goes in to my buckets and I never analyse the logs. If you need it then turn it on.

If you turn it on, then you need to pay the cost of storage. That is all. There is no other costs.

I would also recommend that you set up another bucket called logs.mybucket for all of your logs.